# fpdf is giving UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I am using `fpdf` python package to create a `.pdf` file.

This is my code below:

```
import fpdf
pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format='letter')  # pdf format
pdf.add_page()  # create new page
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=18)  # font and textsize
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="An enhanced Interactive’ Python", ln=1, align="C")
pdf.output("test.pdf")
```

But it is giving me an error as:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 74: ordinal not in range(256)

I am not sure why this is popping up when I want to save the pdf using `pdf.output("test.pdf")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+2019 is the fancy right single quotation mark, which you DO have in your string after the word "Interactive".  I suspect you don't really want that character at all.

Comment: oh . yes, i can see that. yes i don't want that single quotation in the string. But , I am running for large files which may have address with single quotation, what i do i need to do in that case

Comment: It works, i add a line to remove a single quotation from the string. But help will be appreciated,  i don't want to remove the single quotation, how do i go forward wth that

Comment: Regular apostrophes will work just fine.  The fancy quotation marks usually only come from word processing apps like Word.  If you need arbitrary Unicode characters, you can't use FPDF.  There is a UTF-8 version of it called TFPDF.